# D3.js v4 Force layout and fixed node anomaly

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3.js V4 Force layout, comprising two nodes linked by a single edge. One node is fixed near top left, the other free to move.

When the layout is run, the non-fixed node starts in the middle of the layout, and moves away from the fixed node, as though repelled. It ends up in the opposite corner from the fixed node.

I would expect the free node to end up between the centre of the layout (where gravity pulls it) and the fixed node (pulled towards it by the link force). What am I missing, please?

```js
var width = 240,
  height = 150;
var nodes = [
  { // Larger node, fixed
    fx: 20,  fy: 20,  r: 10
  }, 
  { // Small node, free
    r: 5
  }];
var links = [{ // Link the two nodes
    source: 0,    target: 1
  } 
];
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);
// Create simulation with layout-centring and link forces
var force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("centre", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .nodes(nodes);
force.force("link").links(links);

// Draw stuff
var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
  .data(links)
  .enter().append('line')
  .attr('class', 'link');
var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'node')
force.on('tick', function() {
  node.attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.r;
    })
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
  link.attr('x1', function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    .node {
      fill: #f00;
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    .link {
      stroke: #777;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Centering force will try to have the center of mass of all nodes in the coordinate given. As you have 2 nodes and 1 is fixed, the other will be symmetric to the fixed node.

[d3 Centering force documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#centering)

> Centering
>
> The centering force translates nodes uniformly so that the mean
>   position of all nodes (**the center of mass** if all nodes have equal
>   weight) is at the given position ⟨x,y⟩.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was expecting it to work like the gravitational force I used in v3, and always drag towards the centre. I had read the bit you cite, but not digested its implications.